# How to implement PReLU activation in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

The [Parametric Rectified Linear Unit](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852v1.pdf) (PReLU) is an interesting and widely used activation function. It seems that Tensorflow ([reference link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/python/ops/nn.py#L17)) does not provide PReLU. I know that the higher level libraries, such as [Keras](https://keras.io/activations/#on-advanced-activations) and [TFLearn](http://tflearn.org/activations/#prelu), has the implementation of it.

I would like to know how to implement **PReLU** in **Tensorflow**?

Comment: Here is the TFLearn [implementation](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/4ba8c8d78bf1bbdfc595bf547bad30580cb4c20b/tflearn/activations.py#L191) of PRelu. Any specific reason you don't want a dependency on TFLearn?

Comment: I am already a user of TFLearn. But, here I am asking this question in order to learn more of the basic implementation of Tensorflow.

Comment: You should specify what TensorFlow version you have. TF2 has it implemented in Keras: `tf.keras.layers.PReLU`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The implementation of **PReLU** seems straight-forward based on the *PreLU implementations* (see: [Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py#L74), [TFLearn](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/4ba8c8d78bf1bbdfc595bf547bad30580cb4c20b/tflearn/activations.py#L231) and [TensorLayer](https://github.com/zsdonghao/tensorlayer/blob/master/tensorlayer/layers.py#L2635)) of the higher level libraries. My code is as follows:

```
def parametric_relu(_x):
  alphas = tf.get_variable('alpha', _x.get_shape()[-1],
                       initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                        dtype=tf.float32)
  pos = tf.nn.relu(_x)
  neg = alphas * (_x - abs(_x)) * 0.5

  return pos + neg
```

Comment: neg = alphas  * (-x - abs(_x)) * 0.5 how this term comes in picture

Answer (score 11):

Although the solution with `tf.maximum` is very efficient, it can't represent a concave function. Here's a solution that can:

```python
def prelu(_x, scope=None):
    """parametric ReLU activation"""
    with tf.variable_scope(name_or_scope=scope, default_name="prelu"):
        _alpha = tf.get_variable("prelu", shape=_x.get_shape()[-1],
                                 dtype=_x.dtype, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
        return tf.maximum(0.0, _x) + _alpha * tf.minimum(0.0, _x)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it's much easier to implement with `tf.maximum`

My implementation is as following

```
import tensorflow as tf

def PReLU(_x, name=None):
  if name is None:
    name = "alpha"
  _alpha = tf.get_variable(name,
                           shape=_x.get_shape(),
                           initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                           dtype=_x.dtype)

  return tf.maximum(_alpha*_x, _x)
```

Comment: The `tf.get_variable` function is a TF1 function, and is deprecated in TF2.

Comment: _alpha may > 1, so maximum is not a good implementation

Answer (score 2):

PReLU already exists in TensorLayer

http://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers.html#parametric-activation-layer

Answer (score 1):

You have it in Keras implemented as a layer (from version 2.3.0 onwards): `tf.keras.layers.PReLU`. Here is the link to the documentation page: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/PReLU.

It is useful if you want, for example, deploy models with TFLite and used delegates suchas NNAPI, because there are implementations specially for that [NNAPI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/neural-networks#group___neural_networks_1ggaabbe492c60331b13038e39d4207940e0a82e7e7c709ad117a0178203217be30cf)

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Hasnat's answers: (I can't comment yet.. < 50 rep)

If you want more than one different prelu layer, you should set a 'name' parameter:

```
def prelu(_x, name):
"""
Parametric ReLU
"""
alphas = tf.get_variable(name, _x.get_shape()[-1],
                   initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1),
                    dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
pos = tf.nn.relu(_x)
neg = alphas * (_x - abs(_x)) * 0.5

return pos + neg
```

Then you can give each prelu a different name, for example:

```
prelu(x, "alpha1")

# convolution or other

prelu(x, "alpha2")
```

This will resolve the error:

*Variable alpha already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?*